# Есть ли способы построчного чтения из файла в си(на linux)?

Tags: linux, c, unix

Есть ли способы построчного чтения из файла в си(на linux) или единственный способ читать по одному символу до \n?

Comment: [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: Обратите внимание на [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если ты не хочешь написать свою реализацию чтения файла по строкам на `C`, то можно воспользоваться функцией `getline()`  [доки](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("/etc/motd", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

[Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line)